# Creating Dictionary Key and Item When Cell Contains Specific Value Only

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary which only adds a key and item when "ABC" is found in Column N.  They key is a unique ID (Concatenated attributes) and the item is a number.  If the key already exists in the dictionary I want to sum the existing item with the new item (which have the same key / unique ID).

```
Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowForDict As Long
Dim p As Long
dim ws as worksheet
dim LastRowResult as long

set ws = worksheets("DictionaryTest")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ws

    LastRowForDict = .Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For p = 1 To LastRowForDict
If ws.Range("N" & p).Value = "ABC" Then 'only adds to dictionary if line is an "ABC" line


    x = .Range("H2:H" & LastRowForDict).Value
    x2 = .Range("AG2:AG" & LastRowForDict).Value

         'Check if key exists and if yes add new value to existing item (SUM them)

       ''' For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)     should this be here?
If Not dict.Exists(x(p, 1)) Then
    dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = x2(p, 1)
Else          

   dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = CDbl(dict.Item(x(p, 1))) + CDbl(x2(p, 1))
End If
'''next i     should this be here?
End If
Next p


End With

 'map the values
 With ws
    LastRowResult = .Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = .Range("H2:H" & LastRowResult).Value    'looks up to this range
    ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)   '<< size the output array
    For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If dict.Exists(y(i, 1)) Then
            y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
        Else
            y2(i, 1) = ""                                            
        End If
    Next i
    .Range("CK2:CK" & LastRowResult).Value = y2  '<< place the output on the sheet
End With
```

I currently am getting an error (RunTime 9 - Subscript Out Of Range) on this line `If Not dict.Exists(x(p, 1)) Then` and this error occurs on the last row of data on my worksheet (ie. It occurs on `LastRowForDict`). I am thinking this is related to the UBound that I have commented out?  I removed it because it causes the code to run from row 1 to UBound / LastRowForDict every time the "outer" if statement is met.  By this I mean for every "ABC" line, the code runs through all rows on the sheet and thus creates incorrect items.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Your loop is from 1 but your range is one row Smaller than that

Comment: Ahh You are correct.  I changed `x = .Range("H2:H" & LastRowForDict).Value` to  `x = .Range("H1:H" & LastRowForDict).Value` and `x2 = .Range("AG2:AG" & LastRowForDict).Value` to `x2 = .Range("AG1:AG" & LastRowForDict).Value` and this did the trick.  If you would like to post an answer I will mark it correct.  If not I will do it later on!